# Need cube (square) plot for 2 factors factorial design in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, experiment-design

Is there any R package that can produce cube plots for **2** factors (in fact it is a **square** plot)? I want something similar to the first plot at the end of [this page](http://www.processma.com/resource/factorial_plots.htm) on factorial plots.

In the package FrF2 there is the command `cubeplot` but only for 3 factors.

Of course, I can use 2 identical factors, but I want images with nice squares (instead of cubes).

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Andrew. This question seems to be *only* about how to get something done in R. As such, it would be off-topic for CV (see our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq)), but on-topic at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). If you have a substantive question about statistics, please edit to clarify, if your only question is about programming, flag your Q & we can migrate it for you (*please don't cross-post, though*).

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be done with the [scatterplot3d](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterplot3d/index.html) package.  In your case, you would be sure to just have a couple of fixed values of your factors, and not use the ability to plot fully continuous variables.  I have found that the plots made by this package are perfectly adequate for this purpose.

If you really want the full power solution, look into the [rgl](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/index.html) package.  This will allow you to plot 3d images and rotate them.  There is also a function ([snapshot](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/rgl/html/snapshot.html)) that will allow you to take a 2d screenshot of your plot when you've gotten it just the way you want it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not particularly familiar with cube plots, but you could simply plot them out as such. From your link " Each corner of the cube is the average response value for each combination of levels of factors."

Therefore the points are

1. min x, min y
2. max x, miny
3. max x, max y,
4. min x, max y,

last complete the square by repeating the 1st point and plot as line.

```
x<-c(-1,1,1,-1,-1)
y<-c(-1,-1,1,1,-1)
plot(x,y,type="l")
```